# How To add menuItem with list of control bar button in videojs

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I have a control bar with some buttons, but they overlap in mobile, so i want hide some of the buttons and display them in a menuItem when resizing to mobile?
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the buttons you want to hide. For example, className=hideMe. Then in the CSS file, add a responsive media styling

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .hideMe {
       display: none;
     }
   }
```

This will hide those buttons when the screen width is 600px or smaller

Comment: Thanks, but that was not what i was looking for. i updated my question, i want the buttons i hide to appear inside a menu item